# SASS error when using @at-root

Tags: css, sass

I'm running SASS 3.3.0.rc.2 and I've got a strange error.  I've searched Google for any tidbits of information but can't find any.  This file used to work with an earlier version of 3.3.0.   I've removed all SASS gems and re-installed, but it is still happening.  When I try to run Sass on the file I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `tabs' for Sass::Tree::CommentNode:Sass::Tree::CommentNode
```

When I used the `--trace` flag I get the following backtrace:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/tree/visitors/cssize.rb:252:in `block in visit_atroot': undefined method     `tabs' for Sass::Tree::CommentNode:Sass::Tree::CommentNode (NoMethodError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/tree/visitors/cssize.rb:252:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/tree/visitors/cssize.rb:252:in `visit_atroot'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/tree/visitors/cssize.rb:21:in `visit'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/tree/visitors/cssize.rb:41:in `block in visit_children_without_parent'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/tree/visitors/cssize.rb:41:in `map'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/tree/visitors/cssize.rb:41:in `visit_children_without_parent'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/tree/visitors/cssize.rb:30:in `block in visit_children'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/tree/visitors/cssize.rb:61:in `with_parent'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/tree/visitors/cssize.rb:29:in `visit_children'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `block in visit'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/tree/visitors/cssize.rb:223:in `visit_rule'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/tree/visitors/cssize.rb:21:in `visit'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/tree/visitors/cssize.rb:41:in `block in visit_children_without_parent'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/tree/visitors/cssize.rb:41:in `map'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/tree/visitors/cssize.rb:41:in `visit_children_without_parent'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/tree/visitors/cssize.rb:30:in `block in visit_children'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/tree/visitors/cssize.rb:61:in `with_parent'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/tree/visitors/cssize.rb:29:in `visit_children'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `block in visit'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/tree/visitors/cssize.rb:74:in `visit_root'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/tree/visitors/cssize.rb:21:in `visit'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:24:in `visit'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/tree/visitors/cssize.rb:6:in `visit'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:38:in `css_tree'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/engine.rb:275:in `render'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:347:in `update_stylesheet'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:191:in `block in update_stylesheets'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:188:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:188:in `update_stylesheets'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:223:in `watch'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/plugin.rb:108:in `method_missing'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/exec.rb:508:in `watch_or_update'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/exec.rb:346:in `process_result'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/exec.rb:43:in `parse'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/lib/sass/exec.rb:22:in `parse!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0.rc.2/bin/sass:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/sass:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/sass:23:in `<main>'
```

I can't find any information on this and there aren't any new changes to the file.  Any ideas?

EDIT1:  I forgot to mention that I have other files with @at-root being used in them that compile just fine.  Which baffles me even more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that it is in fact a bug.  I've filed it on the SASS project on GitHub and it will be addressed shortly.  Here's a link to the issue for anyone interested or searching:  https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/1082